# How to combine html table row with 1 reference and multiple items?

Tags: laravel, html-table, datatables

I am wondering if its possible to merge rows with same reference id into one but still display its data.
I am using Laravel and Datatables. Any idea?

**From this:**

[image]

**To this:**

[image]

I am using laravel.

**here is my mysql query if it helps:**

```
create temporary table purchasemgmnt
    SELECT item_id,item_name FROM astramc.pm_employee_benefits where isactive = 'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item_id,item_name FROM astramc.pm_furn_fixture where isactive = 'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item_id,item_name FROM astramc.pm_ir_supplies where isactive = 'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item_id,item_name FROM astramc.pm_marketing where isactive = 'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item_id,item_name FROM astramc.pm_office_equipments where isactive = 'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item_id,item_name FROM astramc.pm_office_supplies where isactive = 'Yes';

    create temporary table purchaserequest
    select 
        ppr.pr_id,
        ppri.item_id,
        pm.item_name,
        ppr.remarks,
        ppr.pr_status,
        ppr.date_created
    from pr_purchase_request as ppr
    left join pr_purchase_request_information as ppri
    on ppr.pr_id = ppri.pr_id
    left join purchasemgmnt as pm on ppri.item_id = pm.item_id order by pr_id asc;
        
        
    SET @row_number = 0;
    select 
        @row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS rownum,
        pr_id,
        item_id,
        item_name,
        remarks,
        pr_status,
        date_created
    from purchaserequest order by pr_id asc;
```

**and my laravel view:**

```
@foreach ($pmrequests as $pmrequest)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$pmrequest->rownum}}</td>
        <td><a href="">{{$pmrequest->pr_id}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$pmrequest->item_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$pmrequest->item_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$pmrequest->remarks}}</td>
        <td>{{$pmrequest->date_created}}</td>
        <td>{{$pmrequest->pr_status}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: If you have multiple purchase requests with same pr_id in the pr_purchase_request_information table then you can write a query to group the results by pr_id and then iterate over all items in the group to show as shown above. In that case I don't think you even need to create temporary tables.

Comment: @Donkarnash can u provide a sample code?

Comment: Yes sure @jzoler if you can post the migration for the pr_purchase_request_information table then I can provide a more context near code

Comment: i am not creating a migratin in my app. i just use raw query.

Comment: If you are not writing migration files then how are you structuring i.e creating tables in the database directly importing from previous sql dump? Or using some gui client to create the tables or manually creating tables via cli

Comment: database are previously created by the old developers. so im just using the old database.

Comment: Okay but I guess there would be migration files if the project had been started with Laravel. If it's being converted to Laravel then probably the database could be structured by importing sql dump

Answer (score 0):

Scenario:

Model **PurchaseRequestHeader** - underlying database table `pr_header` has many **PurchaseRequestDetail** - underlying database table `pr_Details`

Define both way relationship in the Model classes

```php
class PurchaseRequestHeader extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pr_header';

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PurchaseRequestDetails::class, 'pr_id', 'pr_id');
    }
}

class PurchaseRequest Detail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pr_details';

    public function header()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PurchaseRequestHeader::class, 'pr_id', 'pr_id');
    }
}
```

Once relationships are defined, we can retrieve all the PurchaseRequestDetail records related/associated with a record of PurchaseRequestHeader.

```php
$data = PurchaseRequestHeader::with('details')->paginate(25);
```

$data will have PurchaseRequestHeader(s) with related PurchaseRequestDetails which can be rendered on the view

```
<tbody>
@foreach($data as $header)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">{{ $header->pr_id }}</a></td>
        <td>
            <table><tbody>
                @foreach($header->details as $detail)
                    <tr>
                        <td> {{ $detail->field1 }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $detail->field2 }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $detail->field3 }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $detail->field4 }}</td>
                    </tr>               
                @endforeach
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: @jzoler Did you get the desired result?

Comment: nope. still the same. i just tried it at the moment. i think this shoul be done in the front-end

Comment: You mean you are not getting the results grouped by `pr_id` ?

Comment: i want to group repeated columns

Comment: I don't quite get it. Can you upload a sql dump of your db if you don't have migration files with some seed data

Comment: my question is very clear. please see attached image

Comment: Is the table shown in the image having data from single database table and is the column with values in blue represent `pr_id` values?

Comment: there are two table. pr_details where the multiples entries are save and pr_header where pr_id is the primary key.

Comment: How is pr_details related to pr_header (foreign key) and can it br assumed that PrDetail and PrHeader are representing models?

Comment: there should be 1 header but multiple details. the only relation between the two tables is the pr_id (the ones with highlighted light blue color)

Comment: @jzoler Have updated the answer, to reflect the relationship between tables